# Javascript Execute onclick event stored in variable

Tags: javascript

I've created the function below to identify an onclick event which is dynamically generated with each page load. I'm able to get the onclick event into a variable (developer console output shown below). I want to execute that onclick event but can't find a good way of doing that. Any assistance is appreciated.

"ƒ onclick(event) {
mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('*lK1129*kWA92AF1C396244F28902B3171F9642E57*x1*t1530820506700','click', self, event)
}"

```
function applyAll() {

    //Get the self Link to click it
    var linkBys = document.getElementsByClassName("mstrmojo-DocTextfield-valueNode");

    // loop through each result
    for(y = 0;y < linkBys.length;y++){

    // retrieve the current result from the variable
    var linkBy = linkBys[y];

    // check the condition that tells me this is the one I'm looking for
    if(linkBy.innerText.indexOf("link") !== -1){
    // Find the right class
    var idy = document.getElementsByClassName("mstrmojo-DocTextfield-valueNode")[y].onclick;
    console.log(idy);   

      }
     }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't idy.click(); work?

Comment: What is that `f onclick(event)` bit at the top with all those characters?

Comment: to quickly note - I am calling the function via an inputbutton which is working fine (it writes to the console on click). I'm just not sure how to execute onclick event contained within the idy variable

Comment: the output with all the weird characters is the dynamic onclick event which which is generated at load time

Answer (score 1):

If the property 'onclick' is defined as a function, you can just run it as a function.

```
var idy = document.getElementsByClassName("")[y].onclick();
```

You could also handle it another way:

```
var idy = document.getElementsByClassName("")[y].onclick;
idy();
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is not an event, it's a function which gets executed when element is clicked. If you want to simulate click you can do `element.click()`

Answer (score 0):

If you used:

```
element.addEventListener('click',()=>...);
```

instead of:

```
element.onclick=()=>...
```

then all you have to do is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mstrmojo-DocTextfield-valueNode")[y].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function returned , adding parens:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function foo() {
            var idy = document.getElementsByClassName("mstrmojo-DocTextfield-valueNode")[0].onclick;
            console.log(idy); 
            idy();//like so
        }
        function alertMe() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" class="mstrmojo-DocTextfield-valueNode" onclick="alertMe();">No click</button>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="foo()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```